# how to convert columns into rows but first two column remain same in sql

Tags: sql-server

how to convert columns into rows but first two column remain same in sql

I have a table where multiple student attendance saved in column
registrstion num
name 
attendance date
attendance status(P,A)

i want to make the report

First Row shows distinct date
Then First two  Column shows Registration num and Name
i want the date will show vartically on name based and horizontal first row date based
SO plz helpt me solve this 
I tried so a=many time using pivot

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please add table structure as well.

Answer (score 0):

For converting columns to rows you can use UNPIVOT. Here there is a documentation about using PIVOT and UNPIVOT.
https://technet.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx